# Get data from php file and parse it into a JS file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file where I retrieved data from the server. I want to parse the data into my pure Javascript file in order to store it in an array.

This is my php code:

```
$dir = "images";
$folders = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
$folders = array_values($folders);
print_r($folders);

$encodedArray = json_encode($folders);

print_r($encodedArray);
```

I want to send over the encodedArray to my pure Javascript file as I want to put them into an array to use. Is it possible to send it to a pure JS file?

Comment: Yes, use an HTTP request (`fetch` / Axios / `XMLHttpRequest`) to load the PHP script that outputs JSON.

Comment: What you are asking has nothing to do with what “parsing” actually means.

Answer (score 2):

you can print your variable JSON "echo $encodedArray",  and you can use fetch to get data from your url. ex: fetch("https://getdatafromserver.php");